# List of all AppleScript commands for Terminal application

Tags: terminal, applescript

In AppleScript we can write things like:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script (someScript)
end tell
```

I mean we are using commands like `activate` and `set currentTab...`.

Where can I find documentation and a full list of all the commands that we can use for Terminal in AppleScript?

Comment: Via the menu in _Script Editor_: _Window > Library_ (⇧⌘L).  This brings up a list of scriptable applications.  Double click on the application whose dictionary you wish to view.  If the application isn’t listed, locate it in _Finder_ and drag-n-drop it onto the _Library_ window to add it to the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **Script Edito**r you can reference the Dictionary:

[image]

Open Script Editor, navigate to **File > Open Dictionary..**.  Choose The Terminal.app

When you click **Terminal Suite** you can see a list of classes:

[image]

If you wanted to get deeper in AppleScript you could buy the application [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com/) version 7, but as noted in the comment there is a free version which is Script Debugger Lite if I recall.  It appears to have an extensive library and utilizes a tree structure separation that helps filter through what you might want.  The referenced image is from Script Debugger 6.

[image]

Comment: _Script Debugger_ is free.

Comment: Script Debugger light is free, the reference image is from Script Debugger 6.  I think they just released a free version.

Comment: Although the object model—which your image shows—isn't available in the free version of _Script Debugger_, the rest of its dictionary is, and even this utility alone is fairly outstanding and a lot more comprehensive than _Scipt Editor_'s version.  So, yes, your recommendation for _Script Debugger_ is a very good one, indeed, whichever route—paid or free—the OP might take.