# Equivalent of xdotool script to open lots of terminal tabs and do actions, on macbook

Tags: terminal, bash, automation

I'm just migrated to macbook from ubuntu, for development.

I had a bash script in ubuntu which opened lots of terminal tabs, and entered various commands in each one, like going to a particular folder, opening some software, ssh-ing onto the live box, etc.  It's my "getting ready to start work" script, that i run when the computer starts up. It's listed below.  It works in quite a primitive way, using xdotool to simulate keyboard and mouse input - everything that I would do if I was doing it manually.

I'd like to run an equivalent on my mac - is there such a thing?  If there are alternatives, which one is easiest to 'translate'? thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
window="$(xdotool search --class mate-terminal | head -1)"
xdotool windowfocus $window

#first cd to our work folder: this will be the base window
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return

#open tab for elearn with mongrel_rails start
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd ~"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "source renametab mongrel"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "mongrel_cluster_start"
xdotool key Return

#open tab for elearn with console start
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd ~"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "source renametab console"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "script/console"
xdotool key Return

#open tab for elearn, don't do anything
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd ~"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "source renametab main"
xdotool key Return

#open tab for elearn, with mysql
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "source renametab mysql"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "mysql -u root e_learning_resource_development"
xdotool key Return

#open three tabs sshd onto live box
#we need to do this now on the live box, to switch to the "nobody" user
#sudo -u nobody bash
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "ssh-live1"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type 'export PS1="$PS1""\[\e]0;live-console \a\]"'
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "cd /path/to/server/folder"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "sudo -u nobody bash"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "script/console production"
xdotool key Return

#same again stay on ubuntu user and don't start console
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "ssh-live1"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type 'export PS1="$PS1""\[\e]0;live1 ubuntu\a\]"'
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "cd /path/to/server/folder"
xdotool key Return

#same again but don't start console
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "ssh-live1"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type 'export PS1="$PS1""\[\e]0;live1 nobody\a\]"'
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "cd /path/to/server/folder"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "sudo -u nobody bash"
xdotool key Return

#open tab and tail the dev log
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
sleep 2
xdotool type "cd $elearn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "source renametab log"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "tail -f log/development.log"
xdotool key Return

#go back to tab 1, then exit
xdotool key alt+1
sleep 2
xdotool type "exit"
xdotool key Return
```

Comment: What kind of research have you already done, including searching for similar questions on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use iTerm2 a free and brilliant terminal and use its  Python API

https://iterm2.com/python-api/

You could use AppleScript  or JavaScript based script with the terminal app

[List of all AppleScript commands for Terminal application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339088/list-of-all-applescript-commands-for-terminal-application)

I would have to check, but there might be something in the new shortcuts app for MacOS . I will check

Update : shortcuts doesn’t have the actions for terminal other than run script.

Don’t forget you can do a lot from command line such as tmux to open multiple consoles or ssh connections, gnu parallel and many tools to to manage tmux sessions.

Comment: Funnily enough one of my colleagues just recommended switching to iterm2, i will check it out, thanks.

Comment: No problem I have just updated my answer. I.e don’t forget solutions which are command line based I.e tmux

Comment: Have a look at smug a tmux session manager https://github.com/ivaaaan/smug

Comment: I've set up an example python script but am struggling with a lack of python knowledge and a lack of simple examples :). ALl i need it to do is to a) open new tabs) b) rename the tabs c) run a list of commands in each tab.  Can you see some documentation for that?  I'm on https://iterm2.com/documentation-scripting-fundamentals.html but can't find those examples...

Comment: https://iterm2.com/python-api/examples/launch_and_run.html

Comment: https://iterm2.com/python-api/examples/index.html

Comment: # Create a new tab, split panes into 2 sessions, set profiles
        tab = await window.async_create_tab()
        split = await tab.current_session.async_split_pane(vertical=True)

    # Sudo to oracle on the left window:
        await tab.sessions[0].async_send_text("sudo su - oracle\n")
 
        # Sudo to root on the right window:
        await tab.sessions[1].async_send_text("sudo -i\n”)

cover in https://jongsma.wordpress.com/2020/02/19/exploring-the-iterm2-python-api/

Comment: thanks - i got it figured out, mostly :)